# Vercel Golang serverless with private dependency

Tags: go, vercel

I have deployed my Golang sls on Vercel, now I'm trying to add one of my private repo as a dependency, but during deployment I'm seeing follwing error

```
Error: Command failed: go mod tidy
go: github.com/user/repo@v0.0.1: reading github.com/user/repo/go.mod at revision v0.0.1: unknown revision v0.0.1
```

the revision/tag exists and I could set up and test everything from local. But I don't see in any [vercel docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/go) how I can configure Vercel to access these private repos. Vercel has read access to my GitHub private repo(dependency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go uses git under the covers to pull dependencies. You need to grant git access to your private repos.

On build system's like `TravisCI`, a typical way to grant such access is through an access token and a `.netrc` file, filling in the secret token via `Travis` stored environment variables:

```
# .netrc
## generate token with https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use
machine github.com login <token>
```

---

**EDIT:**

From the [Vercel Docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes?query=git_cred#advanced-usage/advanced-go-usage/private-packages-for-go):

> To install private packages with go get, define GIT_CREDENTIALS as a build environment variable in vercel.json.
> ...
> With GitHub, you will need to create a personal token with permission
> to access your private repository.

```
{
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "GIT_CREDENTIALS": "https://username:token@github.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but my code is hosted on vercel, Vercel pulls repo from my GitHub, and run `go mod tidy` on it. so the only way to make `.netrc`  file available to Vercel is to commit it to my repo, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @mahendra I've update the answer to include the relevant technique to add a github access token to your build process